# Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can someone help debug this error?

> Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed:
>   nothing to repeat at offset 1

```
//Generate uid
    function gen_uid($len=40) {
        $hex = md5("what" . uniqid("", true));
        $pack = pack('H*', $hex);
        $tmp =  base64_encode($pack);
        $uid = preg_replace("#(*UTF8)[^A-Za-z0-9]#", "", $tmp);
        $len = max(4, min(128, $len));
        while (strlen($uid) < $len)
            $uid .= gen_uid(22);
        return substr($uid, 0, $len);
    }
```

What causes this? Is it a PHP issue or something else? The application works fine on my local machine but not on the server.

Comment: The fact that this would appear to "work fine" on your local machine is alarming. Please enable warnings also in your local machine and investigate why it appears to work, because it should fail for the reason mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @eis, my local insistence displays no warnings or errors.

Comment: and you should enable them, so it would...

Comment: @eis, I enabled them with  ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I figured it out, it has to do with the PHP on the server using a different regex compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`*` in regex means to match the previous character 0 or more times, while `(` starts a capturing group. So, the `*` has nothing to repeat, since what comes before the `*` is a `(`, which cannot be repeated by itself, hence this warning.

To fix it, just escape the `*`, like so:

```
$uid = preg_replace("#(\*UTF8)[^A-Za-z0-9]#", "", $tmp);
```